# How to synchronize photos from MacBook to iPad without erasing photos in iPad?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I used to synchronize photos between PC and iPad. Recently I have a new MacBook and I imported some new photos into iPhoto of the MacBook. Now I need to copy the new photos to the iPad. Can I do this via synchronization (or some other ways) without erasing contents in the iPad? Do I have to first copy the photos from iPad to Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to synch your iPad with the new iTunes on your new machine, your pictures on the iPad will be erased and replaced with the new pictures. You have to copy pictures from iPad to your MacBook then sync with it.

Comment: Do you know any convenient way to do it, if I don't have access to the old computer?

Comment: I also want to preserve the directory structure of the photos in the iPad.

Comment: If I were you and I have access to the old computer, I would export my photo Library and import it to the new computer then synch the iPad with the new computer.

Comment: There are several softwares like this one http://www.ipod-computer.net/guide/copy-photos-from-ipad-to-macbook.html, which you can transfer your photos from iPad directly to your new computer.